# connection between Arduino Uno with nRF24L01 and notebook with wireless card

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, nrf24l01+, wireless, linux

My project intend to command an Arduino UNO by my notebook without cable. I thought to use a RF Nordic nRF24L01 cabled on an Arduino UNO, and to use the wireless card of my notebook to send command to it. Is it possible? Any solution?
Is this hardware solution possible?

I need to send to Arduino four analog signals to setup the light of four led.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no. Can you connect your bluetooth headset to the wireless router? No because even if they share the same band they "speak" different protocols. So why could you do that with the nRF24L01?

If you want to communicate with your PC you have three options:

1. Choose nRF24L01. In this case, since the PC does not have that device, you will need to make an adapter (the easiest one could be an USB adapter). You can connect a microcontroller to a USB to serial converter and to the nRF24L01 and use it as a bridge.
2. Choose Wifi. Then you'll need a new transceiver for the arduino UNO you are using (maybe the ESP8266, which is around 2$) but can be a bit more complicated for just sharing data (I never used it, though, so I can be wrong).
3. Choose bluetooth. Usually this is my preferred way to communicate with a board. Cheap (the HC-06 module is about 2-3 $) and easy to use (the interface is a plain serial).

Good luck ;)

Comment: Might be worth trying the ESP8266 versions with USB interface. Programming them can be as easy as it is with any Arduino if you are using the Arduino IDE. I personally tend to stay away from bluetooth. Turning on bluetooth on my phone / laptop is too much effort:) WiFi is always on anyway.

Comment: @frarugi87, could you suggest a nRF24L01 module with USB adapter for my notebook? And which one for Arduino UNO?

Comment: @larzz11 But you have to implement a more complicated protocol (search for the device in the net, for instance) and I don't know if the ESP supports a direct TCP connection. The BT is much more easy to use (on the PC or phone you have a new serial interface, on the arduino... too ;) ). Anyway what you pointed out about the "turn on/off" is right :P Just one thing: why should you use the ESP USB version? It's easier to connect the arduino to it throigh the serial interface.. The PC is already connected to the wifi :P

Comment: @SPS just go on ebay and search for "nRF24L01 usb". I never used them, though, and I don't know what a "serial adapter" can do because the nRF has an SPI interface. If you want to try you can buy one and see if it works. Personally I'd design my own one using any microcontroller and writing my code...

Comment: @frarugi87 the cheapest solution? to buy another micro-controller (another Arduino??) and nRF24L01 or nRF24L01+USB? Could you provide some examples? Thanks

Comment: @SPS Some examples? go to ebay, write "nRF24L01 USB" to get [these results](http://goo.gl/I0o0I8). I think it's pretty easy..... As for the cheapest solution, probably those module work. You can give them a try... If, on the other hand, you want to spend some time on it, you can buy a board like the arduino nano, or the arduino micro + usb to serial adapter, or just any microcontroller (even an attiny where you can put the USB tiny code to get a HID device)... By the way usually when an answer is "satisfactory" you should accept it...

Comment: You could emulate BTLE with NRF24L01+ if your PC also supports it. Some amount of communication is possible I think but you would have to be quite creative.

Comment: @Avamander never knew you could "fake" BLE with a nRF24L01. Thank you! Anyway you can't receive data on the nRF, just broadcast (so you can only send data FROM arduino TO PC/mobile, and everybody with BT on will see the message). Anyway... Thank you!

Comment: @frarugi87 Is [this](http://www.dx.com/p/usb-wireless-serial-port-to-nrf24l01-module-black-blue-multicolor-421530#.Vp-wqFIXeEw) a complete one (1 module USB for notebook + 1 module on arduino ), good for me? Or do I need another one? I'm a bit confused :-(

Comment: It looks like a good one. But again I never used them, so I don't know how they work. If you can get it to work then share your experience by just saying "Hey, it works" or "Nope, doesn't"